# Why does direction "rtl" stop the button click event from firing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, right-to-left

I have a demo which is working fine (button click is working fine and it moves to next slide). But when I apply direction property on body it stops working fine. My button click handler is not working. My slide does not change.

```js
function handler() {
  document.querySelector(".p").scroll({
    left: 100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handler, false)
```

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.p {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0%;
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute
}

.r {
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}

.bl {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 100px;
}

.g {
  background-color: green;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body class="rtl">

  case : 1
  <div class="p">
    <div class="b r">1</div>
    <div class="b g">1</div>
    <div class="b bl">1</div>
  </div>
  <button id="button">move</button>
  <hr/>

</body>

</html>
```

when you comment the class `rtl` then button click wors. why?

Comment: It doesn't prevent the click from firing. Add `console.log("click");` to the handler and you'll see it. The problem is in the JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is the dependence on "left". When you switch right to left (rtl), all of the code you have that uses "left" has to use "right".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use right-to-left, all horizontal positioning is reversed. You need to use `right` instead of `left` in all the CSS styles. And the scroll amount should be negative to scroll in the opposite direction.

```js
function handler() {
  document.querySelector(".p").scroll({
    left: -100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handler, false)
```

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.p {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0%;
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute
}

.r {
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}

.bl {
  background-color: blue;
  right: 100px;
}

.g {
  background-color: green;
  right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body class="rtl">

  case : 1
  <div class="p">
    <div class="b r">1</div>
    <div class="b g">1</div>
    <div class="b bl">1</div>
  </div>
  <button id="button">move</button>
  <hr/>

</body>

</html>
```